# java Graphics2D set stroke width dynamically

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, stroke

I have this code for Java Paint App.
I have added a slider that changes from 1 to 20 with a default size of 1.This slider is for changing the strokeSize dynamically,so i have created a variable strokeSizeVal and the slider + Listener for it and the new stroke size updates and works just fine, but it updates for all the shapes that are added in the array..Even for shapes that are already drawn.
I save individual stroke weights in a multidimensional array along with the objects.
How can i change this,so that it doesn’t update all the shapes in the array and is valid only for newly created shapes?

I guess this line makes the problem:
graphSettings.setStroke(strokeSizeCounter.next());

thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Lesson48 extends JFrame{
    
    JButton brushBut, lineBut, ellipseBut, rectBut, strokeBut, fillBut;
    
    JSlider transSlider;
    
    JLabel transLabel;
    
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    
    JSlider strokeSizeSlider;
    
    JLabel strokeSizeLabel;
    
    Graphics2D graphSettings;
    
    int strokeSize;
    
    //graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));
    
    int currentAction = 1;
    
    float transparentVal = 1.0f;
    
    Color strokeColor = Color.BLACK, fillColor = Color.BLACK;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new Lesson48();
        
    }
    
    public Lesson48() {
        
        this.setSize(1000, 600);
        this.setTitle("Java Paint");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        
        Box theBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        
        brushBut = makeMeButtons("./src/Brush.png", 1);
        lineBut = makeMeButtons("./src/Line.png", 2);
        ellipseBut = makeMeButtons("./src/Ellipse.png", 3);
        rectBut = makeMeButtons("./src/Rectangle.png", 4);
        
        strokeBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/Stroke.png", 5, true);
        fillBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/Fill.png", 6, false);
        
        theBox.add(brushBut);
        theBox.add(lineBut);
        theBox.add(ellipseBut);
        theBox.add(rectBut);
        theBox.add(strokeBut);
        theBox.add(fillBut);
        
        transLabel = new JLabel("  Transparent: 1");
        
        transSlider = new JSlider(1, 99, 99);
        
        ListenerForSlider lForSlider = new ListenerForSlider();
        
        transSlider.addChangeListener(lForSlider);
        
        theBox.add(transLabel);
        theBox.add(transSlider);
        
        // changing the strokeSize dynamically
        
        strokeSizeLabel = new JLabel("  Stroke: 1");
        
        strokeSizeSlider = new JSlider(1, 20, 1);
        
        ListenerForSlider2 sForSlider = new ListenerForSlider2();
        
        strokeSizeSlider.addChangeListener(sForSlider);
        
        theBox.add(strokeSizeLabel);
        theBox.add(strokeSizeSlider);
        
        buttonPanel.add(theBox);
        
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        this.add(new DrawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        this.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public JButton makeMeButtons(String iconFile, final int actionNum) {
        
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);
        
        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentAction = actionNum;
            }
            
        });
        
        return theBut;
        
    }
    
    public JButton makeMeColorButton(String iconFile, final int actionNum, final boolean stroke) {
        
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);
        
        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(stroke) {
                    strokeColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a Stroke", Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    fillColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a Fill", Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
            
        });
        
        return theBut;
        
    }
    
    private class DrawingBoard extends JComponent{
        
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeFill = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
        
        ArrayList<Float> transPercent = new ArrayList<Float>();
        
        ArrayList<Stroke> shapeStrokeSize = new ArrayList<Stroke>();
        
        Point drawStart, drawEnd;
        
        public DrawingBoard() {
            
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    
                    if(currentAction != 1) {
                    
                    drawStart = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    drawEnd = drawStart;
                    repaint();
                    }
                }
                
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    
                    if(currentAction != 1) {
                        
                        Shape aShape = null;
                        
                        if(currentAction == 2) {
                            aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
                        } else
                            
                        if(currentAction == 3) {
                            aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
                        } else
                            
                        if(currentAction == 4) {
                            aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
                        }
                        
                        shapes.add(aShape);
                        shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                        
                        transPercent.add(transparentVal);
                        
                        //shapeStrokeSize.add(strokeSize);
                        
                        drawStart = null;
                        drawEnd = null;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    
                }
                
            });
            
            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    
                    if(currentAction == 1) {
                        
                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();
                        
                        Shape aShape = null;
                        
                        strokeColor = fillColor;
                        
                        aShape = drawBrush(x, y, 2, 2);
                        
                        shapes.add(aShape);
                        shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                        
                        transPercent.add(transparentVal);
                        
                        //shapeStrokeSize.add(strokeSize);
                        
                    }
                    
                    drawEnd = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
                
            });
            
        }
        
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            
            graphSettings = (Graphics2D)g;
            
            graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            
            graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));
            
            Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
            Iterator<Color> fillCounter = shapeFill.iterator();
            
            Iterator<Float> transCounter = transPercent.iterator();
            
            Iterator<Stroke> strokeSizeCounter = shapeStrokeSize.iterator();
            
            for(Shape s : shapes) {
                
                //graphSettings.setStroke(strokeSizeCounter.next());
                //graphSettings.draw(s);
                
                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transCounter.next()));
                
                graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());
                graphSettings.draw(s);
                graphSettings.setPaint(fillCounter.next());
                graphSettings.fill(s);
            }
            
            if(drawStart != null && drawEnd != null) {
                
                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.4f));
                
                graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                
                Shape aShape = null;
                
                if(currentAction == 2) {
                    aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                } else
                    
                if(currentAction == 3) {
                    aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                } else
                    
                if(currentAction == 4) {
                    aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                }
                
                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
                
            }
            
        }
        
        private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
            
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
            
            int width = Math.abs(x1-x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1-y2);
            
            return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
            
        }
        
        private Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
            
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
            
            int width = Math.abs(x1-x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1-y2);
            
            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
            
        }
        
        private Line2D.Float drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
            
            return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            
        }
        
        private Ellipse2D.Float drawBrush(int x1, int y1, int brushStrokeWidth, int brushStrokeHeight){
            
            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x1, y1, brushStrokeWidth, brushStrokeHeight);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private class ListenerForSlider implements ChangeListener{

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            
            if(e.getSource() == transSlider) {
                
                transLabel.setText("  Transparent: " + dec.format(transSlider.getValue() * .01));
                
                transparentVal = (float) (transSlider.getValue() * .01);
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private class ListenerForSlider2 implements ChangeListener{

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            
            if(e.getSource() == strokeSizeSlider) {
                
                strokeSizeLabel.setText("  Stroke: " + strokeSizeSlider.getValue());
                
                strokeSize = strokeSizeSlider.getValue();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Draw to an off-screen buffer, a BufferedImage, and display this image within paintComponent. This will preserve the old strokes along with their widths. Then when you add new lines to the BufferedImage, use the new stroke width value.

Comment: Note also that 1) you should override `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`, not the `public void paint(Graphics g)` method. 2) Call the super's painting method within your override. So if you are overriding paintComponent, then be sure to call `super.paintComponent(g);` on the first line of the overridden method.

Comment: @user85421 that makes the problem when I start the app that's why I comment it out

Comment: Do you get different colors for each shape? If that logic works then what is the difference between the color and the stroke logic? Instead of creating multiple ArrayLists for Color and Shape and Stroke etc, I suggest you create a single object that contains all the painting properties. For example, check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

Comment: The colors are not the problem, only stroke is changing for all the objects that are already drawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were my project, I'd draw to an off-screen buffer, a BufferedImage, and then display that image in my painting method. This way, the current stroke width would only be used on the newest drawing. I'd also:

- Override paintComponent, not paint
- Draw within a class that extends JPanel and not a JComponent since a JPanel is opaque by default and uses a FlowLayout by default
- Call the super's painting method in my override (`super.paintComponent(g)` if overriding `paintComponent`)
- Not paint points but rather lines
- Create my line starting points, (x1, y1) in a mouse listener's mousePressed method.
- Create and draw a new line on the buffered image within mouseDragged (of a mouse motion listener) and mouseReleased in the mouse listener
- Use a MouseAdapter for both the mouse listener and mouse motion listener.
- I'd extract the value from the slider on mousePressed, when the current lines are first created
- Create my Graphics2D object from the buffered image on mousePressed
- and dispose of it on mouseReleased

For example in the code below I have a BufferedImage is created to fill the drawing JPanel

```
private BufferedImage buffer;
```

I have a nested class called MyMouse that extends MouseAdapter. This allows it to be used as both a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener, and in fact this is what I do in the constructor:

```
MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
addMouseListener(myMouse);
addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
```

In this mouse adapter I override the mousePressed, mouseDragged, and mouseReleased methods.

In mousePressed, I extract a Graphics2D object from the buffered image and get my starting drawing point, my x1, and y1:

```
// mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 

// set my x1 and y1 points for drawing.
x1 = e.getX();
y1 = e.getY();

// create a graphics object to draw to
g2d = buffer.createGraphics();

// smooth the drawing
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

I also get the stroke width selection from the slider and use it to set my Graphics object's Stroke:

```
// use the current stroke width value from the slider
int strokeWidth = strokeWidthSlider.getValue();
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeWidth, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
```

Just for fun, I generate a random color for each brush stroke

```
// generate a random color
float hue = (float) Math.random();
float saturation = (float) (0.5 * Math.random() + 0.5);
float brightness = 1f;
Color randomColr = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, brightness);
g2d.setColor(randomColr);
```

I then draw a "point" by drawing a line of length 0, and then call `repaint()`:

```
// draw a single point
g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);
repaint();
}
```

In mouseDragged and mouseReleased I check to make sure that my graphics object is not null. If it is OK, I get my second point, x2, y2, and draw a line between x1, y1 and x2, y2:

```
if (g2d == null) {
    return;
}
// get the next point
int x2 = e.getX();
int y2 = e.getY();

// draw a connecting line
g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

I then reset x1 and y1 with x2, y2 in anticipation of drawing the next line, and then call `repaint()`

```
// reset the points
x1 = x2;
y1 = y2;
repaint();
```

In mouseReleased I do similar things as above, but then I dispose of the Graphics2D object obtained from the image (it is OK to dispose of a Graphics object that the coder creates, but never do this to a Graphics object given to you by the JVM, such as given via a `paintComponent` method):

```
// same as mouseDragged:
if (g2d == null) {
    return;
}
int x2 = e.getX();
int y2 = e.getY();

g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
repaint();

// dispose of the Graphics object
g2d.dispose();
g2d = null;
```

Then, all the painting method has to do (again here, it is paintComponent, not paint) is draw the buffered image, if it is not null:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);  // Don't forget this!!!!
    if (buffer != null) {
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call the super's method so that housekeeping painting will be done.

---

The whole shooting match:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Lesson48b extends JPanel {
    private static final int BI_WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int BI_HEIGHT = 600;
    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private JSlider strokeWidthSlider = new JSlider(0, 20, 1);
    private JButton cleaButton = new JButton("Clear");

    public Lesson48b() {
        // give the drawing a white background
        clearImage();

        strokeWidthSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        strokeWidthSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        strokeWidthSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        strokeWidthSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        strokeWidthSlider.setOpaque(false);
        add(strokeWidthSlider);

        cleaButton.addActionListener(e -> clearImage());
        add(cleaButton);

        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    private void clearImage() {
        buffer = new BufferedImage(BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
        g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT);
        g2d.dispose();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (buffer != null) {
            g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private int x1, y1;
        Graphics2D g2d;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // set my x1 and y1 points for drawing.
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();

            // create a graphics object to draw to
            g2d = buffer.createGraphics();

            // smooth the drawing
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // use the current stroke width value from the slider
            int strokeWidth = strokeWidthSlider.getValue();
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeWidth, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

            // generate a random color
            float hue = (float) Math.random();
            float saturation = (float) (0.5 * Math.random() + 0.5);
            float brightness = 1f;
            Color randomColr = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, brightness);
            g2d.setColor(randomColr);

            // draw a single point
            g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (g2d == null) {
                return;
            }
            // get the next point
            int x2 = e.getX();
            int y2 = e.getY();

            // draw a connecting line
            g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            // reset the points
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (g2d == null) {
                return;
            }
            int x2 = e.getX();
            int y2 = e.getY();

            g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            repaint();

            // dispose of the Graphics object
            g2d.dispose();
            g2d = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Lesson48b mainPanel = new Lesson48b();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Paint");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(mainPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't have that in mind, but it helps a lot
Thank you very much